# Python's in (__contains__) operator returns a bool whose value is neither True nor False

Tags: python, boolean, membership, comparison-operators

As expected, 1 is not contained by the empty tuple

```
>>> 1 in ()
False
```

but the `False` value returned is not equal to `False`

```
>>> 1 in () == False
False
```

Looking at it another way, the `in` operator returns a `bool` which is neither `True` nor `False`:

```
>>> type(1 in ())
<type 'bool'>
>>> 1 in () == True, 1 in () == False
(False, False)
```

However, normal behaviour resumes if the original expression is parenthesized

```
>>> (1 in ()) == False
True
```

or its value is stored in a variable

```
>>> value = 1 in ()
>>> value == False
True
```

This behaviour is observed in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Can you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are running into comparison operator chaining; `1 in () == False` does **not** mean `(1 in ()) == False`.

Rather, comparisons are chained and the expression really means:

```
(1 in ()) and (() == False)
```

Because `(1 in ())` is already false, the second half of the chained expression is ignored altogether (since `False and something_else` returns `False` whatever the value of `something_else` would be).

See the [comparisons expressions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

For the record, `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`, `is`, `is not`, `in` and `not in` are all comparison operators (as is the deprecated `<>`).

In general, don't compare against booleans; just test the expression itself. If you *have* to test against a boolean literal, at least use parenthesis and the `is` operator, `True` and `False` are singletons, just like `None`:

```
>>> (1 in ()) is False
True
```

This gets more confusing still when integers are involved. The Python `bool` type is a subclass of `int`<sup>1</sup>. As such, `False == 0` is true, as is `True == 1`. You therefor can conceivably create chained operations that almost look sane:

```
3 > 1 == True
```

is true because `3 > 1` and `1 == True` are both true. But the expression:

```
3 > 2 == True
```

is false, because `2 == True` is false.

<sup>1 <sub>`bool` is a subclass of `int` for historic reasons; Python didn't always have a `bool` type and overloaded integers with boolean meaning just like C does. Making `bool` a subclass kept older code working.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. Wouldn't dream of comparing against a boolean expression in real life, but stumbled over this curiosity while trying to explain to someone why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @user2949478: and now you have *another* reason! :-)

Comment: This looks to me like it violates the principle of least astonishment.  I can see expressions like `a is b is None`, and `1 < x < 10`, but not mixes between `in`, `not in`, `is`, `is not`, with each other, or with the (in)equality operators.