# if True and if False statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've always been confused about using True and False on if statements. For instance, let's say that I've defined a function that returns True or False.

```
def isEven(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now I need to use that function on one of my code which can only proceed if the number is even. I believe I have seen codes like `if isEven(number): proceed etc etc`, my question is, is it considered True by default? Or should I keep using `if isEven(number) == True`

Comment: You should never test `== True`; you don't need to, and you could run into [comparison operator chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19751556) giving you confusing results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have something like that :

```
if myboolean : ...
```

it means "if myboolean is true, then do whatever is after". So it's the same as :

```
if myboolean==true : ...
```

Comment: How about if I need a False before proceeding to the statement? Should I then use `if myboolean == False` ?

Comment: Exactly. You don't need to do `if myboolean == true`, because it's implicit, but if you need it to be false to continue, you have to do something like that : `if myboolean==false`

Comment: @HeroStradivari It would be idiomatic to use  `if not myboolean: ...`

Answer (score 3):

Both uses are exactly the same. In

```
if expr:
    pass
```

first `expr` is evaluated so you get

```
if True:
    pass
```

or

```
if False:
    pass
```

no matter what the original `expr` was.

PS:

Now, I always found the `if True: return True` pattern obsolete. Why not `return True` directly. That is:

```
def isEven(number):
    return (number % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just use

```
if isEven(number):
   # proceed
```

It only has a possible different meaning if isEven doesn't return `True` or `False`

For example `1`, `2`, `3` etc. are treated as True
`None`, `0`, `[]` etc are treated as False

Additionally, you have the same type of redundancy in your function

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0
```

works just as well. The following works too, but is less clear

```
def isEven(number):
    return not number % 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if isEven(number):
```

will execute the indented code after if when isEven returns True

You don't need to check **isEven(number) == True**