# Storing unique string using if no in == False

Tags: python, list

writing a simple code to store unique string into `list`. However if i use  `if var in list == False` the string output = `blank`. However if i use `If var not in list`, I gotten the desired output.

please advise why `if var in list == False` does not work here.

```
bank = list()

while True:
      word = input('Enter a word,type"done"to finish')

      if word == 'done': break

      if word in bank == False: # this code does't work as intended
            bank.append(word)

bank.sort()
print(bank)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's in (\_\_contains\_\_) operator returns a bool whose value is neither True nor False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751556/pythons-in-contains-operator-returns-a-bool-whose-value-is-neither-true-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit subtle but its because of [Comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). Comparitors `< | > | == | >= | <= | != | is [not] | [not] in` have equal prescience and are compared left to right. In addition, chaining of the operations is the same as adding an "and". The familiar example is:

> `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`.

The same holds for `in`. Your expression is the same as

```
if (word in bank) and (bank == False):
    ....
```

Your working example `if word in bank:` is the canonical way of writing the expression... no need to make it complicated!

Answer (score 1):

@tdelaney gave the correct above.  Here is how you would write it:

```
if word not in bank:
  bank.append()
```

Or even better use a set instead of a list.

```
bank = set()
while True:
  word = input('Enter a word,type"done"to finish')
  if word == 'done':
    break
  bank.add(word)

bank = list(bank)
bank.sort()
print(bank);
```

Comment: OP already knows this way works. The question is why the other doesn't.

Comment: Fair enough.  Revised answer.

Comment: Still not quite right. These operators all have the same precedence and `word in False` is a `TypeError`.

Comment: I am not getting a TypeError when I tried it.

Comment: @tdelaney good comments, referred your answer and left the set suggest for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because it represents it like:

```
if word in (bank == False):
```

It's like the order of operations in math, so it takes it first processes whether `bank` is `False`, not processing first whether `word` is in `bank`, so if you use parenthesis, it would work:

```
if (word in bank) == False:
```

If you change it to the above ^, it would work.

But of course it's more recommended if you use:

```
if word not in bank:
```

Comment: That's not quite it. `if word in (bank == False):` raises a `TypeError` because `(bank == False)` is a boolean, which doesn't handle the `in` operation.